# Simple past and past perfect tense

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

Stories are mostly written in simple past tense.(let's call it past 1) To explain an event that happened even before past 1 we use past perfect tense.(let's call it past 2) Now if we want to add a dialogue in past 2, what shall we write 'he said" Or "he had said"?

Like:
He had sold the monkey.
"It is another mouth to feed," he said/ he had said/he would say.

Comment: We don't normally ***keep using*** Past Perfect just because we need to refer to more than one action that happened earlier than the current "narrative reference time". Your example doesn't give any indication of why you used Past Perfect for ***had sold*** anyway - but even assuming you had good reason for using it in the first sentence, most native speakers / writers wouldn't ***repeat*** it (they'd use ***he said***, not ***he had said***). Note that ***he would say*** only applies if that's something the subject repeatedly / habitually said in the past (*unlikely*, but *possible* here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If you are writing a long passage in past perfect, is it acceptable to only use it at the beginning and end?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151274/if-you-are-writing-a-long-passage-in-past-perfect-is-it-acceptable-to-only-use) Also [past simple or past perfect in this case](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/) and [Is it necessary to repeat "had" in the following sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62537/) and [Repeating HAVE (or other auxiliary verb) in one sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118350/), among others.

Comment: If the story is being told through the eyes of one of the characters and that person is briefly thinking back to the sale of the monkey, you can use 'he had said' - but if you are writing a long description of an earlier episode, as FumbleFingers says, it would be tedious to keep on using the past perfect.